# How to make const member-functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function, methods, constants, php-5.5

I was studying what my book called "constant member functions" in C++. That is, functions that can not change any attribute of the class or call other methods that are not constants. So, I made this code in **C++**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Foo
{
    string outra_coisa;
  public: 
    void printa_algo(string algo) const;
};

int main()
{
    Foo tolo;
    string alguma_coisa = "coisa_alguma";
    tolo.printa_algo(alguma_coisa);

    return 0;
}

void Foo::printa_algo(string algo) const
{
    cout << algo;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same **in PHP**?

Comment: @PaulCrovella thanks man...But, are you sure about that? Have not an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some research I saw in a book that it is not possible, at least is not trivial, to create such functions in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same concept on the "compiler" level you can create static methods which are not exactly the same but should also "not change any class property or use its instance".

```
class Foo {
    public static function bar()
    {
        return 'a static value';
    }
}
//Then to call it:
Foo::bar();
```